# How to determine which heroku buildpack to use when multiple are available?

Tags: heroku, buildpack

Obviously selecting the right buildpack is critical in order to make secure, performant, and resilient applications. Heroku seems to work with the dev community to create and share buildpacks. A side effect is that there may not be a single, 'obvious' choice for a given tech stack.

**Random example (R)**

If we wish to use an R buildpack, a quick google show this popular buildpack is out of date and no longer supported, but we can easily find these three (just examples) [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/dpmccabe/heroku-buildpack-r), [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/hmdc/heroku-buildpack-r), and [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/wjjung317/heroku-buildpack-r)

**Another random example (cairo)**

The cairo buildpack - googling shows numerous in the top results, it's not clear which to use out of, say, the top four on google [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/blackandredinc/heroku-buildpack-cairo), [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/withcopper/heroku-buildpack-cairo), [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/amondo/heroku-buildpack-cairo) (this one clearly states deprecated, so we can rule that out), and [here](https://github.com/mojodna/heroku-buildpack-cairo)

#### Question

What are the main criteria against which we should assess heroku buildpack when faced with >1 that look like they will do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer here depends on how much you're willing to trust someone else's code.

None of the buildpacks you mentioned are officially supported by Heroku. They are community buildpacks, maintained by the community, and they implement the Heroku Buildpack API.

The Buildpack API is open for anyone to implement. So the most discerning users will write their own buildpacks. Otherwise, you'll have to decide which community you *trust* the most.